# Aspose Slides Dotnet Core Linux, failing to get thumbnail

Tags: image, .net-core, aspose, aspose-slides

When Running a basic test of aspose slides in DotnetCore6 Linux I get the:

> System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception.
> ---- System.PlatformNotSupportedException : System.Drawing.Common is not supported on non-Windows platforms. See https://aka.ms/systemdrawingnonwindows for more information.
> Stack Trace:
> at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipCreateBitmapFromScan0(Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 stride, Int32 format, IntPtr scan0, IntPtr& bitmap)

Exception.

simple Example:

```
 var pres = new Presentation(fn);
        for (var page = 0; page < pres.Slides.Count; page++)
        {
            ISlide slide = pres.Slides[page];
            
            slide.GetThumbnail());//.Save($"{_currentDir}/output/{origfn}_{page + 1}.tiff");
        }
```

I have referenced:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Aspose.Cells" Version="22.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Aspose.Email" Version="22.7.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Aspose.Imaging" Version="22.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Aspose.PDF" Version="22.7.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Aspose.Slides.NET" Version="22.7.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Aspose.Words" Version="22.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="BitMiracle.LibTiff.NET" Version="2.4.649" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Aspose.Slides does not support .NET 6 yet.
.NET 6 support is still planned for Aspose.Slides 22.11. I work at Aspose.

**UPD:** Aspose.Slides supports .NET 6 at the moment.